# Makefile dependencies variable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a simple Makefile. When i'm NOT using a variable in dependencies list it works fine. Otherwise it gives fallowing error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'ext/configXML.o', needed by 'libledrgb-jni.so'.  Stop.
```

Furthermore when i do

```
    make print-LED-CFG-SRC
LED-CFG-SRC = ../led-cfg/src
```

So the value is set properly, altough if I explicitly add rule for this file:

```
ext/configXML.o: $(LED-CFG-SRC)/%.cc 
@echo 'Building file: $<'
@${CXX} $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o "$@" "$<"
```

It looks like the problem is with the LED-CFG-SRC to source file:

```
 make ext/configXML.o
make: *** No rule to make target '/configXML.cc', needed by 'ext/configXML.o'.  Stop.
```

But the file exists:

```
   make list
ls -la ../led-cfg/src
total 340
drwxrwxr-x  2 gigi gigi  4096 lip 27 13:10 .
drwxrwxr-x 12 gigi gigi  4096 lip 28 10:08 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 gigi gigi 11918 lip 28 09:54 configXML.cc
-rw-rw-r--  1 gigi gigi  2891 lip 27 13:17 configXML.h
```

Here's the source Makefile:

```
    EXTOBJS = ext/configXML.o ext/packet.o ext/tinyxml2.o ext/crypt.o ext/rozkaz.o
    LED-CFG-SRC := ../led-cfg/src/ 
    INCLUDES := -I$(LED-CFG-SRC)
    CXXFLAGS := $(INCLUDES)
    LIBRARY := libledrgb-jni.so

    CXXFLAGS := $(INCLUDES) -fPIC -std=c++14

    all: dirs $(LIBRARY)

    $(LIBRARY): $(OBJFILES) $(EXTOBJS)
        $(CXX) -shared -o $@ $^



    ext/%.o: $(LED-CFG-SRC)/%.cc 
        @echo 'Building file: $<'
        @${CXX} $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o "$@" "$<"


    clean:
        rm -rf $(EXTOBJS)

    list:
        ls -la $(LED-CFG-SRC)

    print-%  : ; @echo $* = $($*)


    .PHONY: clean dirs
```

I'm using GNU Make 4.1

Comment: Look at the value printed with `make print-LED-RGB-SRC`. It says `../LED/source/src/`, not `../led-cfg/src/`.  Typo somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, I've printed out different variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shot in the dark. At least in the `Makefile` listing you have posted, there is a redundant undesired whitespace in the definition of the `LED-CFG-SRC` variable:

```
LED-CFG-SRC := ../led-cfg/src/<there-is-reduntant-whitespace-here>
```

That means, when the variable is expanded in the rule definition later, the `make` would see `../led-cfg/src/ %.cc` (two words, `$<` = `../led-cfg/src/`, and `%.cc` being only as a additional dependency) instead of the expected `../led-cfg/src/%.cc`.

You should activate display of non-printable characters in your editor, since `make` in places is extremely picky about the whitespaces: some it chooses to strip automatically, but some it keeps. Like here: `make` had stipped the whitespace in the front of the `../led-cfg/src/`, but it kept the one at the end.

Comment: Good spot. I have never had such issues because my editor strips trailing whitespace on save.

Comment: This just bit me with a var defined as `VAR := <blah> # Description of var`. Never would have guessed!